# fmd is invalid using android studio with digital persona SDK

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble with creating fmd from byte. Error with fmd is invalid.
Here is my code

```
String id = jsonobject.getString("fps_thumb");

byte [] encodeByte= Base64.decode(id,Base64.DEFAULT);

Fmd m_fmdAuxiliar = UareUGlobal.GetImporter().ImportFmd(encodeByte, Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004, Fmd.Format.ISO_19794_2_2005);
```

Does anyone know?

Comment: Could you post the error, please?

Comment: the error is only on catch statement saying FMD is invalid. Im tryng to save the data coming from the reader to save it on the database (which is send through api to laravel backend) then retrieve the data in android studio (java) and comapre the difference

Answer (score 0):

this is the code for retrieving data from api and compare it from the reader finger print

```
try{
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(http.getResponse());
        for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = jsonobject.getString("fps_thumb");
        byte[] bytes = id.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        try {
        Fmd m_fmdAuxiliar = UareUGlobal.GetImporter().ImportFmd(bytes, Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004, Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004);
        m_score = m_engine.Compare(m_fmdAuxiliar, 0,m_engine.CreateFmd(cap_result.image, Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004), 0);

        DecimalFormat formatting = new DecimalFormat("##.######");
        m_text_conclusionString = "Dissimilarity Score: " + String.valueOf(m_score)+ ", False match rate: " +
        Double.valueOf(formatting.format((double)m_score/0x7FFFFFFF)) + " (" + (m_score < (0x7FFFFFFF/100000)
        ? "match" : "no match") + ")";

        Log.i("TAG",m_text_conclusionString);

        } catch (UareUException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: this is the code for retrieving data from api and compare it from the reader finger print